# Approximations of Polylogarithm and Lerch transcendent?

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, polylogarithms

For the Gamma function $\Gamma(x+1)$, we have beautiful approximations of the function in terms of elementary function, such as the Stirling approximation and its refinements, that give sharp estimates even for small values of the parameter, say $x\geq 1$.

Are there known approximations of the Polylogarithm $\mathrm{Li}_s(z)$ and the more general Lerch transcendent $\Phi(z,s,a)$ (as a function of $z$) in terms of elementary functions that give reasonably sharp estimates for all (or at least a wide range of) $z>0$? Ideally, I'm looking for sandwiching upper and lower bounds, but any estimator with good multiplicative error will be interesting.

Comment: I would use $\Gamma(s) \text{Li}_s(z) = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x/z-1}dx$

Comment: That's an integral representation of the function. I'm referring to a high-quality approximation (not exact value) in terms of elementary functions (the right-hand side of your identities are not elementary functions even if the functions inside integral are elementary). Gamma function can, in turn, be approximated by Stirling-type estimates and would be OK.

Comment: @MCH did you find anything since asking this question?